# Laravel 4: Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel v4.2 and getting the following error:

```
Class UserController does not exist
```

Here is my code:

**user.php**

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function index(){
        return View::make('/')->with('title', 'Home | Public Review');
    }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get( '/', array(
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'UserController@index'
) );
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: `php artisan dump-autoload`?  Is your controller in `app/controllers/`?  What if you name the file `app/controllers/UserController.php` (instead of `user.php`)?

Comment: Thanks @bishop. I changed my user.php to UserController.php and it's working now. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically, in Laravel 4, you'll find `class UserController` residing in `app/controllers/UserController.php`.

Laravel [doesn't actually care](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#basic-controllers), so long as the class in your routes.php can be auto-loaded.  Consequently, always consider running `php artisan dump-autoload` after class name or class file name changes to ensure the autoloader is updated.

Comment: I have same issue. As per your suggestion I tried to run php artisan command, but getting error also on that which is ' "dump-autoload" is not defined.' I'm using laravel 5.0

Comment: it's "composer dump-autoload" and not "php artisan dump-autoload"

Comment: @Alucard: That also works: `artisan dump-autoload` is a super-set of `composer dump-autoload` (or locally `php composer.phar dump-autoload`).

Answer (score -1):

Is because the correct is composer dump-autoload